# Columnstore indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I am just looking for some input from those who have been using columnstore indexes for some time.

I have a non-transctional table - essentially no updates or deletes, only inserts of about 10 k rows will be performed every day & we'll write select queries on a handful of columns. Does it make sense to have a columnstore index or traditional clustered/non clustered index in this case.

This table will have no foreign keys etc and there is a small chance of data for a given date being deleted etc, once or twice a month.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Without any information on the shape of the data or the queries, it's hardly possible to make index recommendations. You could just try and see. 10K rows is not much; even after a year you would only have 3.7M rows, which is substantial but hardly enormous. On any modern server, with those loads it'll take a while before you notice the difference between any indexing scheme.

Comment: Create indexes based on what columns you search on the most. Then show your execution plans for the queries and see where your bottlenecks are.

Comment: Note that it's not a binary choice between a columnstore index *or* traditional indexes. In SQL Server 2016+ you can freely combine them, and have a clustered columnstore index with non-clustered B-tree indexes, or a clustered B-tree index with a nonclustered columnstore index. Obviously, switching between clustered index types is expensive and requires rebuilding the table, but you can at least always opt to add indexes (and in most scenarios, starting off with a traditional B-tree index and adding a columnstore afterwards is the less invasive choice).

Comment: Thanks All. I also just realized that in sql server 2012, a delete statement requires columnstore index to be disabled or deleted..

Answer (score 1):

With 10k rows, it is hard to see a big advantage for a column-store index.  It is possible if your columns are wide.  But if your columns are just normal columns, I would suggest keeping the records together.  Columnstore indexes are going to be more valuable when you have lots and lots of records.

In practice, all 10k rows are going to be loaded into memory anyway.

If there are a handful of columns that are used by almost all queries, with a scattering of columns that are rarely used, you might consider storing the two sets of columns in different databases.

Comment: Yes, I understand 10 k is minuscule data set to test. We have 350 columns on this table..  We will be selecting random columns based on the query and report - by using a key and a date column in this table.